Separating Strings into Dataframe
I have a problem that I've searched for and every solution led to another problem. I have a large unstructured dataset (4000+ rows). There are 24 columns but only the 1st column has all the data in it.
*Edit: I should provide extra context, there are 24 total column headers for the sake of the example I only listed a few. There also seems to be 25 values to correspond to the 24 rows. I know that will become an issue at some point.
Example:
name                          age height weight
"Jones, Mike",24,72inch,90kg

Its like that for 4000+ rows. I need to be able to separate each comma into the corresponding column. I've used str.split with a comma as my delimiter, but there are commas within quotes that I need to ignore. I converted it  into list and I used the below code to fix it and it seemed to work:
import re
PATTERN = re.compile(r'''((?:[^,"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)''')
PATTERN.split(lista)[1::2]

but I can't verify it because I can turn it into a DF because I get an error "Dataframe constructor not properly called!"
Here are my questions:

How do I convert my list into a DF?
How do I verify the values with a comma within it will be seen as one whole value ("Jones, Mike" & not "Jones, [then] Mike")


How did you read the data? Reread the data using pandas.read_csv skipping the first row of headers as it does not have the delimiter

Yes, this is how I read the data. In the raw excel CSV file it's unstructured in the way I listed it above

I think I have a solution, but I'm hung up on one thing: "There also seems to be 25 values to correspond to the 24 rows." - What does that look like? In the example data, you have 4 values for 4 column headers. (I assume you meant "24 column headers" when you said "24 rows". And I'm assuming the non-header data is CSV using quotes.)

@AlmightyAK This code doesn't open any files or read any data (from disk, URL, DB, or otherwise), so Onyambu is asking, how did you read the data?

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. You can [edit] to improve your post.

IMO it would be helpful to show a couple of lines from your csv file.

To separate your data into a DataFrame when your data has commas within quotes, you can use Python's built-in csv module or directly utilize pandas.read_csv which is highly optimized for handling such cases. Here are two approaches:
Approach #1 using csv module:
You can use the csv.reader to accurately parse the rows that include commas inside quotes, treating strings such as "John, Mike" as single entries:
import csv

# you could replace this with the actual file read
data = [
    '"Jones, Mike",24,72inch,90kg',
    '"Doe, Jane",30,65inch,120kg'
]

parsed_data = []
for row in data:
    reader = csv.reader([row])  # csv.reader expects an iterable of strings (each being one line)
    parsed_data.extend(reader)

Printing the parsed_data after this looks like:
[['Jones, Mike', '24', '72inch', '90kg'], ['Doe, Jane', '30', '65inch', '120kg']]

From there, you can convert the List to a DataFrame with pandas (specify your column names corresponding to your data).
import pandas as pd

columns = ['name', 'age', 'height', 'weight']
df = pd.DataFrame(parsed_data, columns=columns)

Finally printing df.head() just to verify all is right would look like:
          name age  height weight
0  Jones, Mike  24  72inch   90kg
1    Doe, Jane  30  65inch  120kg

Approach #2 using pandas.read_csv:
Using pandas.read_csv would simplify the process as it directly handles CSV files including those with commas within quotes:
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO  # used here for demonstration with string data

# sample data
data = '''
"name",age,height,weight
"Jones, Mike",24,72inch,90kg
"Doe, Jane",30,65inch,120kg
'''

# read data using pandas (replace StringIO(data) with your file path)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

Once again, printing df.head() just to verify all is right would look like:
          name age  height weight
0  Jones, Mike  24  72inch   90kg
1    Doe, Jane  30  65inch  120kg

Recommendations:

For simpler scripts or when working directly within Python scripts, using csv.reader can be very flexible.
For handling files, especially large ones, and for using DataFrame operations, pandas.read_csv is more efficient and brief.


I tried this but when I print parsed_data I only get the column headers

This works, but Pandas has this functionality built in with read_csv, so why not use that? It's much more direct.

iter seems to be redundant since reader is iterable

@AlmightyAK - This might occur if the data input to the csv.reader is limited to just the header or if there's an issue with how the rows are iterated. Ensure that all rows of data are included in the data list would be my best answer to that.

@wjandrea This is true, pandas.read_csv simplifies the process significantly. It's optimized to handle CSV data directly, including cases with commas within quotes, which is a common format issue & correct for the point about iter. The csv.reader object is already an iterator, so wrapping it with iter was unnecessary. You can directly iterate over the reader.

pandas.read_csv is really good for this type of problem:
from io import StringIO
import csv
import pandas as pd

lista = """name                          age height weight
"Jones, Mike",24,72inch,90kg
"Doe, John",32,68inch,85kg
"""

sio = StringIO(lista)

df = pd.read_csv(sio, skiprows=1, names=['name', 'age', 'height', 'weight'])
print(df)

Output:
          name  age  height weight
0  Jones, Mike   24  72inch   90kg
1    Doe, John   32  68inch   85kg


I'm also new to stack but this seems like a simple solution. The problem originates from the dataset being badly structured as it has "nested" values of last name and first name. We need to fix that.
For every row you want to extract the "Jones, Mike", separate it with str.split and create a new row with values Mike and Jones separate.
You can then add this new formatted row to the dataframe, however you like, row-by-row, etc.
Here are a few ways you can add a row to a dataframe object. From Pandas Add or Insert Row to DataFrame - Spark By {Examples} by Malli

# Quick examples of adding row to dataframe

# Example 1: Add row to dataframe
list_row = ["Hyperion", 27000, "60days", 2000]
df.loc[len(df)] = list_row

# Example 2: Insert dict as row to the dataframe 
# Using DataFrame.append()
new_row = {'Courses':'Hyperion', 'Fee':24000, 'Duration':'55days', 'Discount':1800}
df2 = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

# Example 3: Add new row to specifig index name
df2 = df.append(pd.DataFrame([new_row],index=['7'],columns=df.columns))

# Example 4: Append row to the DataFrame
df2 = df.append(pd.Series(new_row, index=df.columns, name='7'))

# Example 5: Using pandas.concat() 
# To add a row
new_row = pd.DataFrame({'Courses':'Hyperion', 'Fee':24000, 'Duration':'55days', 'Discount':1800}, index=[0])
df2 = pd.concat([new_row,df.loc[:]]).reset_index(drop=True)

# Example 6: Add specific row/index name 
# Using DataFrame.loc[]
df.loc['7', :] = ['Hive',25000,'45days',2000]

# Example 7: Add row in DataFrame 
# Using DataFrame.loc[]
df.loc['7'] = ['Hive',25000,'45days',2000]



Adding rows to a dataframe is an anti-pattern. See cs95's answer on "Creating an empty Pandas DataFrame, and then filling it"

This doesn't even really answer the question, because once you have Mike and Jones separate, what column(s) do you insert them into in the dataframe? OP's code doesn't create a dataframe at all, so there's not enough info to fill in the gaps.
